# How to add or minus 1 month from current date?

Tags: swiftui

I need to be able to add or minus 1 month from the current date.

So far I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DateView: View {
    static let dateFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy MMMM")
        return formatter
    }()

    var date = Date()

    var body: some View {

        HStack {

            Button(action: {
                print("Button Pushed")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                .padding()
            }

            Spacer()

            Text("\(date, formatter: Self.dateFormat)")
            Spacer()

            Button(action: {
                print("Button Pushed")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                .padding()
            }

        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}

struct DateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DateView()
    }
}
```

I would like to change the date displayed to be +1 month or -1 month depending on which chevron I will tap.

I am new to swift and swiftui and don't know what action I should use. I think it's related to DateComponents, but what should I do about it now? I am stuck. Please help me.

To better visualise what I have and want to do, here is an image of my current result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Calendar` to add or subtract months/days/hours etc to your `Date`. Apple's documentation on the `Calendar` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar).

Below is a working example, showing how to increase/decrease the month by 1.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    static let dateFormat: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy MMMM")
        return formatter
    }()

    @State var date = Date()

    var body: some View {

        HStack {

            Button(action: {
                print("Button Pushed")
                self.changeDateBy(-1)
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    .padding()
            }

            Spacer()

            Text("\(date, formatter: Self.dateFormat)")
            Spacer()

            Button(action: {
                print("Button Pushed")
                self.changeDateBy(1)
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    .padding()
            }

        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }

    func changeDateBy(_ months: Int) {
        if let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: months, to: date) {
            self.date = date
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you for super fast answer, @Andrew. I don’t have a laptop with me right now. I will check it in the morning. Thank you very much!

Comment: I was going to post a similar answer. This works @mallow!

Comment: @Andrew, Thank you very much! Works great! :)

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5**

Function to add or subtract month from current date.

```
func addOrSubtractMonth(month: Int) -> Date {
    Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: month, to: Date())!
}
```

Now calling the function

```
// Subtracting
var monthSubtractedDate = addOrSubtractMonth(-7)

// Adding
var monthAddedDate = addOrSubtractMonth(7)
```

- To Add date pass prospective value
- To Subtract pass negative value

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58712921/2227743).

Comment: @EricAya you are right but when I was finding the solution I was unable to find this solution form the accepted clumsy code. I just try to write it simple. Thank you..